# html geocode not getting coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

here is my code in document ready,

```
$("document").ready(function(){

          function getUserLocation(){
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              alert("test");
              var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                 console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                  $.ajax({
                      url : ajaxurl,
                      type : 'post',
                      data : {
                        action : 'df_location_search',
                        lat : position.coords.latitude,
                        lng : position.coords.longitude
                      },
                      success : function(ipg_response) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(ipg_response);
                          alert("mak");
                          if(response.success==1){

                          }
                      }
                  });
              });
            }  
          }
          getUserLocation();
});
```

problem => no getting coordinates before sending ajax request, console.log(position.coords.latitude); not any data is showing , even undefined value is not showing in console, can anybody help?

Comment: I just pasted your code into codepen and it seems to be returning the coords just fine. Perhaps it's your browser permissions being set not to allow getting location?
https://codepen.io/tinusw/pen/zdMoee?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

The problem i checked was, my site was not on https protocol, it was on demo link, so it gave me error ,

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   for more details.

and when i switched this code to live domain, with https protocol, it works fine for me, so should test your code in the environment you have to deploy your app.